# Can I kill console-kit-dae process on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The top Command shows 2 processes of console-kit-dae, each using 22% of memory.

I would like to know why, and if I can kill them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking into these links that explain what console-kit-dae is. [consile-kit-dae forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=58757) And the [official web page](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit)